# Laravel localization of validation rule 'before' and 'after' with parameter like 'today/tomorrow'

Tags: php, validation, laravel, date, laravel-5

Lets assume I have this rules in my model:

```
public $rules = [           
        'a_date'  => 'after:today',
        'b_date'  => 'before:today',
    ];
```

And I have this string in my `project\resources\lang\en\validation.php`:

```
    'after' => 'The :attribute must be a date after :date.',
    'before' => 'The :attribute must be a date before :date.',
```

I translate them into some language in `project\resources\lang\some-language\validation.php`

```
    'after' => ':attribute *somelanguage* :date.',
    'before' => ':attribute *somelanguage* :date.',
```

But when I hit validation error in my app I see string like that:
`*field* *some language* today` 
 (for example in Russian:`Поле a_date должно быть раньше чем today`)

So **the question is**: How and where to replace this `today`(*and any other predifined words like that*) to desired localization?

PS: I could use a custom validation as stated in docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#localization 
 but it only aplied to certain fields and I wish it to replace `today` whenever I use it in any of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array in your lang file (in my case it was `title.php`):

```
'time_periods' => [
        'yesterday' => 'вчера',
        'now'       => 'сейчас',
        'today'     => 'сегодня',
        'tomorrow'  => 'завтра',
    ],
```

And then add the following code in `CustomValidator` class:
*All this code does is replacing parameters in certain rules with values from your lang file array using keys of this array. First it changes english replacer to localized one and then use it to replace the actual placeholder(`:date`) in validation message.*

```
    class CustomValidator extends Validator {
        public function replaceBefore($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {                
            $parameter_translated = str_replace(
                array_keys(trans('title.time_periods')),
                array_values(trans('title.time_periods')), 
                $parameters[0]
            );
            return str_replace(':date', $parameter_translated, $message);
        }

        // this method does the same but for 'after' rule
        public function replaceAfter($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
            $parameter_translated = str_replace(array_keys(trans('title.time_periods')), array_values(trans('title.time_periods')), $parameters[0]);
            return str_replace(':date', $parameter_translated, $message);
        }
    }
```

If you don't like to have `CustomValidator` then use this approach (taken from [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules) , see: 'Defining The Error Message' part):

> When creating a custom validation rule, you may sometimes need to
>   define custom place-holder replacements for error messages. You may do
>   so by creating a custom Validator as described above then making a
>   call to the replacer method on the Validator facade. You may do this
>   within the boot method of a service provider:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Bootstrap any application services.
>  *
>  * @return void
>  */
> public function boot()
> {
>     Validator::extend(...);
>
>     Validator::replacer('foo', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
>         return str_replace(...);
>     });
> }
> ```